# Can anybody tell me what are the first 3 derivatives for this function?

Tags: derivatives

Let 
$$M_X(t)=\frac{e^t}{2-e^t} \text{ with } t<\log2.$$
What are the first $3$ derivatives?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you know? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? People will probably downvote this question and vote to close it unless you show some effort of your own.

Comment: I'm stuck on how to find the derivatives

Comment: Do you know the quotient rule?

Comment: Either use the quotient rule to differentiate the function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) or you can always let Wolfram Alpha differentiate the function: https://www.wolframalpha.com. Just type in the function you want and tell it to take the derivative. If you need help applying the quotient rule I can write an answer, just tell me.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to calculate them is to rewrite first this formula as
$$f(x)=\frac{\mathrm e^t-2}{2-\mathrm e^t}+\frac{2}{2-\mathrm e^t}=-1-\frac 2{\mathrm e^t-2}$$
Remember
$$\Bigl(\frac1u\Bigr)'=-\frac{u'}{u^2},\qquad\Bigl(\frac1{u^2}\Bigr)'=-\frac{2u'}{u^3}, \qquad\Bigl(\frac1{u^3}\Bigr)'=-\frac{3u'}{u^4}.$$
Now 
$$f'(x)= \color{red}{2\frac{e^t}{(e^t-2)^2}}= 2\frac 1{\mathrm e^t-2}+4\frac1{(e^t-2)^2},$$
so
\begin{align}f''(x)&=-2\frac{e^t}{(e^t-2)^2}-8\frac{e^t}{(e^t-2)^3}= \color{red}{-2\frac{e^{2t}+2e^t}{(e^t-2)^3}}\\
&=-2\frac 1{\mathrm e^t-2}-12\frac1{(e^t-2)^2}-16\frac1{(e^t-2)^3},\end{align}
and finally
$$f'''(x)=2\frac{e^t}{(e^t-2)^2}+24\frac{e^t}{(e^t-2)^3}+48\frac{e^t}{(e^t-2)^4}= \color{red}{2\frac{e^{3t}+8e^{2t}+28e^t}{(e^t-2)^4}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

it is better to simplify the function before taking the derivatives 
$$\frac{e^t}{2-e^t}=\frac{2-2+e^t}{2-e^t}=-1+\frac{2}{2-e^t}$$
so
$$M(t)=-1+2(2-e^t)^{-1}$$